# Shell script find and substitute

Tags: bash, shell, sed

i am trying to search an xml file and replace a certain character so that i all 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT are replaced with 5.0.0, using shell script

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.verio.oss.common</groupId>
   <artifactId>oss-common-parent</artifactId>
   <name>oss-common-parent</name>
   <version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <description>MarketPlace SuperPOM</description>
<modules>
   <ui-server-svcs-version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</ui-server-svcs-version>
   <ui-client-svcs-version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</ui-client-svcs-version>
   <ui-widgets-version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</ui-widgets-version>
   <ossb-billing-version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</ossb-billing-version>
   <ossb-integration-version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</ossb-integration-version>
   <oss-ems-config-version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</oss-ems-conf>
<properties>
   <skipTests>true</skipTests>
   <app-version>${project.parent.version}</app-version>
   <app-build-date>09/27/2011</app-build-date>
   <app-build-number>1</app-build-number>
   <app-build-revision>101</app-build-rev>
```

i tried this script but it didnt work, any help will really help

```
#!/bin/bash
search="(1\.5.\1-\SNAPSHOT\)"
rep="(\5.\0.\0)"
sed -i.bak 's/${search}/${rep}/g' nameoffile.xml
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a number of issues with your script.

1. line 6 contains `fi` without any matching `if` before
2. The regular expression you are searching for should rather be `1\.5\.1-SNAPSHOT` and the replacement a simple `5.0.0`
3. Using `'` instead of `"` in your call to sed `${search}` and `${rep}` will not be interpolated. Try using `"` instead. As pointed out in the comment section don't forget to qoute shell metacharacters in this case.

`sed s/1\\.5\\.1-SNAPSHOT/5.0.0/g` should be the whole script you need to do the job.

Note the double `\` to escape the one `\` you want in your regexp for the shell.

Comment: also the parens around the search regexp won't hurt (but they won't help either) but around the replacement string they will appear as-is. You also don't need to escape `.`s in a replacement string.

Comment: can someone show me, how the full script will look like because i make the changes but i still get error

Comment: whee! that's true. I remved escaped `.`s in rep. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You're having to double-escape the metacharacters because you aren't quoting the script.

Comment: @EdMorton: just added that in the "full scrip" version asked for. Thanks again for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.sh
search="1\.5\.1-SNAPSHOT"
rep="5.0.0"
sed "s/${search}/${rep}/g" file

$ ./tst.sh  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.verio.oss.common</groupId>
   <artifactId>oss-common-parent</artifactId>
   <name>oss-common-parent</name>
   <version>5.0.0</version>
   <description>MarketPlace SuperPOM</description>
<modules>
   <ui-server-svcs-version>5.0.0</ui-server-svcs-version>
   <ui-client-svcs-version>5.0.0</ui-client-svcs-version>
   <ui-widgets-version>5.0.0</ui-widgets-version>
   <ossb-billing-version>5.0.0</ossb-billing-version>
   <ossb-integration-version>5.0.0</ossb-integration-version>
   <oss-ems-config-version>5.0.0</oss-ems-conf>
<properties>
   <skipTests>true</skipTests>
   <app-version>${project.parent.version}</app-version>
   <app-build-date>09/27/2011</app-build-date>
   <app-build-number>1</app-build-number>
   <app-build-revision>101</app-build-rev>
```

Add the `-i` arg back when you're happy with it.

Note that this will falsely match on the middle section of `3411.5.1-SNAPSHOTISH` or similar - if that's a problem, add boundaries to the regexp, e.g.: `search=">1\.5\.1-SNAPSHOT<"` and account for them in the replacement.